# Nonsense edit by community bot approved?

Tags: discussion

Why was this edit [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58812797/revisions)?

Edit text:

> nothing LOLLOLOLOLLOLInvdsnfvhudsanhuresnyvufydhsufnvd

Edit added:

> LOLOLOL

to the end of an answer. Edit was approved by [Adam Strauss](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26807269)

Comment: Adam Strauss is the author of the answer, so he can single-handedly approve suggestions. Might be a misclick, or maybe he just wanted the notification to go away and clicked something at random

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that he was the author. I have suggested another edit.